# Literature references for why and how flow expands when it leaves a hole

Tags: fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations, flow

So I’m in high school and I’m doing research on fluid dynamics. However I can’t find any references for how a fluid flow expands when it leaves a nozzle/hole.

For exemple, when I blow, I can feel the flow in a small region of my hand when it’s close to my mouth, but if I move my hand just a feel centimeters away, the cross-sectional area of the flow becomes bigger than my hand.

My intuition says it’s because the viscous forces of the moving fluid on the “boundary layer” (I don’t now if I can call it that) end up transferring momentum to the stationary fluid. But I still need a mathematical model for how this happened and how it depends of the relevant parameters, such as the Reynolds numbers.

It’s probably a stupid question and I’m getting unlucky when searching for key-words, but It would be of great help if any of you enlighten me on the subject.

Btw, sorry for possible English mistakes, it’s not my first language. I’ve tried to make it as clear as possible, but I feel that I end up just sounding like an 4 yo.